# Override minor mode keybinding in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, minor-mode

I am using paredit (a lisp minor mode) in emacs.
Paredit binds `C-<left>` and `<C-right>` to barf and slurp sexp which I don't like.

I am trying to set back the keybindings to `left-word` and `right-word`

If I evaluate in a buffer (that uses paredit mode) the following code I successfully overwrite the bindings:

```
 (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") 'left-word)
 (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") 'right-word))
```

However, when I try to `eval-after-load` the same thing in `init.el` it has no effect.

```
 (eval-after-load "paredit-mode"
    '(progn
       (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") 'left-word)
       (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") 'right-word)))
```

I have added the above code at the end of my `init.el` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `(eval-after-load "paredit"...)` instead of `(eval-after-load "paredit-mode"...)`.

The first argument to `eval-after-load`, `FILE` is a file name or a feature name. `paredit-mode` is the name of a command (and a mode), not a file or feature name. The file is `paredit.el`.

Comment: That did it, thank you. I guess next time I'll read the documentation more carefully.

Comment: thank you so much! this also did the trick for the same issues with `smartparens`:
```(eval-after-load "smartparens"
  '(progn
       (define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") 'left-word)
       (define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") 'right-word)))
```